# setup upgrade get the area code is not set error

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

After I use composer to install a new extension, I was trying to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
but it throws this error "Area code is not set"

I am running Magento 2.4.3-p1

I did google but did not find any result. It just happen suddenly.

Please help
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you install any custom module and when you run upgrade command and got this error then you need to add following code in your custom module **setup/InstallData** file...

```
public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
        ...
    ) {
        try {
            $state->getAreaCode();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($e->getMessage() == 'Area code is not set') {               
  /* missing - after $state  */
```

$state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

I **encountered** the similar issue **`during Magento upgrade(commerce cloud 2.3.7 to 2.4.5-p1)`**. I had several custom modules installed. I found the issue when I started debugging. **The issue was throwing from some of the custom commands file.**

**I disabled them from the respective di.xml and the errors were gone**. There was something wrong in the file. I **fixed the issue** and ran the setup upgrade, it **started executing without any errors**.

**Note:** Don't update anything in the core files which is not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered this problem after an upgrade, after a long search i found that one of the modules in app/code had template files that didn't have a **frontend** or **adminhtml** **parent folder**!

That was the reason of the error. Area code was indeed not set.